# Send multiple attachment in mail phpmailer

Tags: php, backend, phpmailer

if code first time run other form then form still submit and mail receive but particular form submit mail not sent getting error. commented part working fine but i want one logic to all form

```
  if (!!$filename) {
          if(str_contains($filename, '#')){
           $filename_arr = explode("#",$filename);  
            $target_path_arr = explode("#",$target_path);
            
            foreach( $filename_arr as $k => $v ){

                $mail->addAttachment($target_path_arr[$k], $v); 
            }     
            // $mail->addAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/document/mobile-app-requirements-specifications-document-template.docx", "mobile-app-requirements-specifications-document-template.docx");
            // $mail->addAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/document/Agicent-General-Capabilities-Presentation-2022.pdf","Agicent-General-Capabilities-Presentation-2022.pdf");
            // $mail->addAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/document/5-Points-committment.png", "5-Points-committment.png");
        }else{
                $mail->addAttachment($target_path, $filename);
        }
        }
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking or what your issue is. Have you looked at [the multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps)? If you're attaching local files you've already got, you can skip the part for handling uploads.

Answer (score -1):

Read and try to understand below function maybe it will help you .

```
  public function fnSendMailCareg($xlspath,$xlspath1,$xlspath2,$from,$to,$subject,$message,$cc1,$cc2,$cc3='',$cc4='')
{

    include_once APPPATH . "third_party/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
    include_once APPPATH . "third_party/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";
    include_once APPPATH . "third_party/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
    if(isset($to)) {
        $spilt = explode('@',$to);
        $e = $spilt[0];
    }
    if(isset($from)) {
         $spiltf = explode('@',$from);
         if($spiltf[0] == 'support') $f = 'John_doe- '.$spiltf[0];  else $f = $spiltf[0];
    }

    // Instantiate a new PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

    // Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->setFrom($from, $f);  //i.e FROM email address
    $mail->addAddress($to, $e);// i.e TO email address

    if(isset($cc1)) {
        $spilt1 = explode('@',$cc1);
        $e1 = $spilt1[0];
        if(isset($e1) && $e1 != ''){
            $mail->AddCC($cc1, $e1);
            }
    }
    if(isset($cc2)) {
        $spilt2 = explode('@',$cc2);
        $e2 = $spilt2[0];
        if(isset($e2) && $e2 != ''){
            $mail->AddCC($cc2, $e2);
            }
    }
    if(isset($cc3)) {
        $spilt3 = explode('@',$cc3);
        $e3 = $spilt3[0];
        if(isset($e3) && $e3 != ''){
            $mail->AddCC($cc3, $e3);
            }
    }
    if(isset($cc4)) {
        $spilt4 = explode('@',$cc4);
        $e4 = $spilt4[0];
        if(isset($e4) && $e4 != ''){
            $mail->AddCC($cc4, $e4);
            }
    }

    if(isset($cc4) && $cc4 != ''){
        $MyCustomBcc = $cc1.",".$cc2.",".$cc3.",".$cc4;
    }else if(isset($cc3) && $cc3 != ''){
        $MyCustomBcc = $cc1.",".$cc2.",".$cc3;
    }else{
        $MyCustomBcc = $cc1.",".$cc2;
    }

    $mail->Username = '**************';
    $mail->Password = '****************';
    $mail->Host = '*****************';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    // Enable TLS encryption over port 587
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->AddAttachment($xlspath);
    $mail->AddAttachment($xlspath2);
    $mail->AddAttachment($xlspath3);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    if($mail->send()) {
        
        $response = 'Success';
    }
    else{
        $response = 'Fail<br>'. $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    return  $response;
}
```